# problem with my function with discord.js for my bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to create a script to know which one has my bot in servers and create my an invitation, the second I want to create a command who send one private message to all members (no its not a raid bot)

1. script :

```
    client.on("ready", () => {
    client.user.setActivity('ESPADA');
        client.guilds.forEach(serv => {
          serv.channels.random().createInvite().then(invite => console.log(`>${serv.name} | ${invite}`))
          .catch(console.log(`>${serv.name} | Entrain d'envoyer une invite... `));
        });
```

2. and my error :

   (node:10752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
       at Client.client.on (c:\Users\mathis\Downloads\self bot ash\Raid.js:10:18)
       at Client.emit (events.js:189:13)
       at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:433:17)
       at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:417:10)
       at WebSocketShard.shard.on.unavailableGuilds (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:199:14)
       at WebSocketShard.emit (events.js:189:13)
       at WebSocketShard.checkReady (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:466:12)
       at WebSocketShard.onPacket (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:438:16)
       at WebSocketShard.onMessage (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
       at WebSocket.onMessage (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
3. my DM command

   ````
       if(message.content === "!mp"){
           if(message.deletable) message.delete();
           i = 0;
           message.guild.members.forEach(member => { ```

   4. the error :

   TypeError: message.guild.members.forEach is not a function
       at Client.<anonymous> (c:\Users\mathis\Downloads\self bot ash\Raid.js:98:31)
       at Client.emit (events.js:194:15)
       at MessageCreateAction.handle (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
       at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
       at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
       at WebSocketShard.onPacket (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:435:22)
       at WebSocketShard.onMessage (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
       at WebSocket.onMessage (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
       at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
       at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (c:\Users\mathis\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:801:20)
   ````

thank you for the repply!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with your discord.js version being v12 or greater (At least in your DM Command).
As of v12, [Client#guilds](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) and [Guild#members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) no longer return a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection)
instead they return a `Manager`. So now `Guild#members` returns a [`GuildMemberManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager) and Client#guilds returns a [`GuildManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager).
 
Luckily there's still a way to gain access to the respective collections of Managers, and thats via: `<SomeManager>.cache`.
The `cache` property is in every single Manager without exception (As it's a property within the [`BaseManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/BaseManager)).
So to gain access to the `client.guilds` or `guild.members` collections you'd do the following:
`Client#guilds`:

```js
// This returns the collection: Collection<Snowflake, Guild>
// which then you can use methods on such as .forEach() or .every()
client.guilds.cache; 

// Using .forEach()
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => console.log(guild.name));
```

and `Guild#members`:

```js
// This returns the collection: Collection<Snowflake, GuildMember>
// which then you can use methods on such as .forEach() or .every()
guild.members.cache;

// Using .forEach()
guild.members.cache.forEach(member => console.log(member.displayName));
```

There are a few other Manager types, I'd recommend consulting [**this**](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache) to see the changes in v12. The older tutorials on youtube use discord.js v11 or under and I haven't seen any updated versions yet.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use `every` rather than `forEach`; I have encountered problems like this before.

P.S. if this is a selfbot, keep in mind that they are against Discord's [terms of service](https://discordapp.com/terms).